# Google Site link reporting We're Sorry

Tags: security, google-sites

We have a curriculum site hosted in New Sites and is shared publicly. Anyone that visits the site gets the Google "We're Sorry" page and can't access the website without refreshing the page multiple times. It seems that after you finally get each page to show, future visits are fine. But as they begin to roll this site out to teachers, they need the link to work. This is both via direct link access or clicking the link in an email. Happens in Chrome and Firefox so far from testing.

I've never seen this happen with Google Sites. There is nothing specific on the page that is unsafe, no insecure embeds (just images and links to google drive docs).

I used https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search to test and it comes back safe.

Per request I am going to include screenshots from the Network tab. However I can no longer replicate this issue on my network or machines, but many teachers are still reporting the issue so trying to get screenshots from them. In this first one, logimpressions is blocked for them but the site loaded - this is most likely caused by having uBlock enabled.
[image: Test Screenshot with loading but logimpresssion blocked]

Comment: The next time it happens, can you open the web tools (F12) and tell us what you see in the network tab?

Comment: I will ask around for help as I can't recreate it anymore on my machine. Though we are still having teachers experiencing it. I included a screenshot of the network tab with it loading. The only error I see is with logimpressions but that browser has uBlock enabled.